# How to get record from database between two dates and time?

Tags: mysql, winforms

I am taking date request from the server in the UI:

`request.date_from = dateTimePickerFromDate.Value; //7/31/2017 12:33:18 PM
 request.date_to = dateTimePickerToDate.Value; //7/31/2017 12:33:18 PM`

*Data is not getting displayed as the time is same for date_from and date_to*

And in the database I have the SQL query:

`@date_from datetime, @date_to datetime`

`select Transaction_date from Transaction
where (Transaction_Date >= @date_from and Transaction_Date <= @date_to) order by Transaction_date desc`

I am getting data if I choose different date, ***but if I select same date, data is not getting displayed although I have records in the database because of same time.***

As I want to display records between the date **7/31/2017 00:00:00** and **7/31/2017 23:59:59** What changes do I need to make either in the SQL query or else in winforms UI ?

Comment: if you use the same date for `@date_from` and `@date_to`, you will only get records who have the exact date. In your case, I think, there are no exact matches.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hey Ben, I have records in the database let's say ranging from **2017-07-31 10:50:47.043** and **2017-07-31 19:07:07.137**                      Date is same and time are different. So, if I select same date I should be able to get data between two different time having same date.

Comment: if you want all records of a day, you should set `@date_from` to 2017-07-31 00:00:00 and `@date_to` to 2017-07-31 23:59:59.

Comment: Ben, It works fine if I put date and time manually, But what if I am getting data from the database:                                                                                          `select Transaction_date from where (Transaction_Date >= @date_from and Transaction_Date <= @date_to) order by Transaction_date desc` Entering date in winforms dateTimePicker

Comment: try to add one day to the `@date_to` object

Answer (score 1):

Use Between in query

`select * from table where {date_filed} between {start_data} and {end_date}`

Or you can use

`select * from table where {date_filed} >= {start_data} and {date_filed} <= {end_date}`

but in both date date field need to datetime or timestamp datatype otherwise use str_to_date its use in type case in mysql query

Comment: Priyanka, I am using this :   `select Transaction_date from where (Transaction_Date >= @date_from and Transaction_Date <= @date_to) order by Transaction_date desc`   which is similar to `select * from table where {date_filed} >= {start_data} and {date_filed} <= {end_date}` I suppose. How about the same date but different time ?

Comment: its working for the same date also(Today morning I have used it) here table name is missing I am sure its a mistaken but still I am inform you 

did you data type is datetime or timestamp?

Comment: It was a typing error. For both the date, data type is datetime.

Comment: @Rudra:- You are right if date are same day its not working because its take '2017-01-01 :00:00:00' like this so need to change into query now its

`SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE Transaction_Date >= '2017-07-01 00:00:00' and  Transaction_Date <= '2017-07-01 23:00:00'`

and same in between query

Comment: Priyanka, How to put in this query: `select Transaction_date from where (Transaction_Date >= @date_from and Transaction_Date <= @date_to) order by Transaction_date desc`

Comment: @Rudra:- if you want compare only betwwn date use date() function like 
`where date(date_field) >= date and date(date_field) <= date`

Comment: Priyanka, I wan to compare both date and time, so if the date is same but the time is different, then also data should get displayed. Currently, I am getting the data for the different date but for the same date I'm facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two DatePicker controls on your form. I would add one day to `dt_to`.

```
var dt_from = dateTimePicker1.Value;
var dt_to = dateTimePicker2.Value;
if (dt_from.Date == dt_to.Date)
    dt_to = dt_to.AddDays(1);
```

**[Update]**

```
request.date_from = dateTimePickerFromDate.Value; 
request.date_to = dateTimePickerToDate.Value;
if (request.date_from.Value.Date == request.date_to.Value.Date)
    request.date_to = dt_to.Value.AddDays(1);
```

**[Update 2]**

```
request.date_from = dateTimePickerFromDate.Value; 
request.date_to = dateTimePickerToDate.Value;
if (request.date_from.Value.Date == request.date_to.Value.Date)
    request.date_from = request.date_from.Value.Date;
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and it's not taking dt_from.Date    Acually .Date is not acceptable.

Comment: What is not taking `dt_from.Date`?

Comment: I am using this:  `request.date_from = dateTimePickerFromDate.Value;
            request.date_to = dateTimePickerToDate.Value;`     date_from and date_to carries dateTime data type.  And then I use your code `var dt_from = request.date_from;
            var dt_to = request.date_to;

            if (dt_from.Date == dt_to.Date)
                 dt_to = dt_to.AddDays(1);`  It gives error stating **'DateTime?' does not contain definition for Date and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (missing a using directive or assembly reference)**

Comment: Think your `date_from` and `date_to` are nullable DateTime objects. Try the following: dt_from.Value.Date

Comment: I updated my answer and used your objects to store the DateTimes from the DateTimePickers

Comment: Ben It worked fine. Thank you. But my concern is I am selecting same date and sending request to the server, i.e. `date_from = dateTimePicker1.Value; // 2017-08-01 04:50:23` and `date_to = dateTimePicker2.Value; // 2017-08-01 04:50:23` So using your method, it adds my date_to `2017-08-02 04:50:23` So it displays data for 2017-08-02. I hope you got my point.

Comment: you only want the range from 2017-08-01 04:50:23 to 2017-08-02 00:00:00?

Comment: Is there any way which sets my date_from to date I want to select but the time "00:00:00" and date_to with the time I wan to select with time "current time in the system"

Comment: Ben, I want the range from 2017-08-01 00:00:00 to 2017-08-01 04:50:23

Comment: Updated my answer again. Now you are getting the range as expected, when both Date Properties are equal.

Comment: It's working fine as i wanted it to work. Thank you so much Ben.

Comment: Ben, if you have time I also want to ask you something. I have a data in server database having time `2017-07-31 17:05:27.487` but when its getting displayed on a data table in my system it shows different time `2017-07-31 10:05:13` Do you know the reason why?

Comment: first thing I was thinking of was utc and local time, but without knowing what's going on, it is difficult to answer. You should create a new question.

Comment: Okay Ben, I'll create a new question. But, I appreciate you for taking out time for answering my silly questions. Thank you.